# Apps Crashing Due to Mishandling of Fetching Fonts

Tags: applications, font, font-book

I recently downloaded two apps from the Mac App Store, and I appear to be having the same problem with both applications. Both applications open, but as soon as I click on anything, they crash. The two apps are called “Tap Forms Organizer 5” and “Aktuell 3.” They are not made by the same developers.

I have contacted the developers for both apps. I provided both with the error reports generated upon crashing. Both indicated it was a problem fetching fonts.

I went into the FontBook and selected all fonts, then validated all fonts. All came back valid.

Then I went into System Profiler, and went down to “Fonts.” Here, I again confirmed all fonts are valid.

It was suggested that I download, install, and run [“Font Doctor,”](http://www.fontdoctor.com) but this is a $69.99 application that I would not get much use out of.

**I am on a 13” MacBook Pro with Retina, running El Capitan (10.11.6).** Both apps are compatible with my rMBP (the correct versions of the apps have been installed, as there are multiple versions of each of the two apps). The installed fonts appear valid.

*In your experience or research, have you come across such an issue and its resolution?*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I use an app called "TinkerTool" that allowed me to change the system font. I went into TinkerTool, and under "Fonts," I clicked "Restore to Defaults."

Problem solved.